# How to pass class variable inside lambda expression?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I am trying to learn threading in c++.

I have implemented [Bounded Buffer - producer/consumer Simulation](https://www.studytonight.com/operating-system/bounded-buffer), but I am facing some error in passing class variable in the lambda expression.

I am facing issue in passing one of the class variable in lambda expression inside one of the class member functions.  I have tried passing my variable in **capture clause** and **parameter** , but I am still getting error.

```
class example {
     private : 
         vector<int> storage;
     public :
         void outsideCallFunction(int x) {
               auto lambdaFun = [&storage] () {
                    if(storage.size() > 50) return true; // FACING ISSUE HERE , NOT ABLE TO ACCESS storage variable in side the lambda function, I have tried many different ways of passing as parameter, as 
                    else return false;
              // using lambdaFun ahead in the code
               }
         }
}
```

Please go ahead and copy paste the code in your editor. I am facing issue in lineNumber 21 and 30 ( both are same issue actually ).

I am new to c++ lambda expressions, I would be grateful if someone can help me understand the problem and explain the solution. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <thread> 


using namespace std;

class ProducerConsumerSimulation {
    private :
        vector<int> storage; // common storage, where we store data, which is critical section, so we need to use mutex.
        mutex storageMutex;
        condition_variable storageConditionVariable;
    public :
        void publish(int x) {
            /*
                if Storage is having 50, dont push any more elements, wait for consumer to consume some data. 
            */
            unique_lock<mutex> storageUniqueLock(storageMutex);
            // how to pass storage in lambda
            storageConditionVariable.wait( storageUniqueLock, []() {return storage.size() > 50 ? false : true; } ); // if the storage is full , then wait for consumer to consume it
            storage.push_back(x);
            storageConditionVariable.notify_one();
        }
        int consume() {
            /*
                consume data, until there is some data in storage, otherwise wait for producer to push data. 
            */
            unique_lock<mutex> storageUniqueLock(storageMutex);
            // how to pass "storage" in lambda 
            storageConditionVariable.wait( storageUniqueLock , []() { return storage.size() > 0 ? true : false ; });
            int returnVal = storage.back();
            storage.pop_back();
            storageConditionVariable.notify_one();
            return returnVal;
        }
};

void publishMethod(ProducerConsumerSimulation &simulationObject) { // publisher is one thread that is publishing data object
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        int randomNumber = rand() % 20;
        simulationObject.publish(randomNumber);
    }
}

void consumeMethod(ProducerConsumerSimulation &simulationObject) { // consumer is one thread which is consuming data from object
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        int result = simulationObject.consume();
        cout << " consumer thread got result " << result << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ProducerConsumerSimulation simulationObject;

    thread publisherThread(publishMethod, std::ref(simulationObject));
    thread consumerThread(consumeMethod, std::ref(simulationObject));

    publisherThread.join();

}
```

I have tried passing class variable in CAPTURE CLAUSE [] and in PARAMETER () . But didn't work out.

Comment: Just capture `this`, e.g. `auto lambdaFun = [this] () { return (storage.size() > 50); };`

Comment: @fabian, I have tried adding "this" and "this.storage.size()", but that also didn't work.

Comment: `this` never was something other than a pointer, so you cannot use `.` to access it's members (and you don't need to explicitly use it). `this->storage.size()` would be what you need, but unless there's a name conflict, `this->` can be left out the same way you could leave it out, if it was used in the member function body directly...

Comment: okay, understood now. thanks . I will try and let u know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <thread> 


using namespace std;

class ProducerConsumerSimulation {
    private :
        vector<int> storage; // common storage, where we store data, which is critical section, so we need to use mutex.
        mutex storageMutex;
        condition_variable storageConditionVariable;
    public :
        void publish(int x) {
            /*
                if Storage is having 50, dont push any more elements, wait for consumer to consume some data. 
            */
            unique_lock<mutex> storageUniqueLock(storageMutex);
            // how to pass storage in lambda
            storageConditionVariable.wait( storageUniqueLock, [&]() {return storage.size() > 50 ? false : true; } ); // if the storage is full , then wait for consumer to consume it
            storage.push_back(x);
            storageConditionVariable.notify_one();
        }
        int consume() {
            /*
                consume data, until there is some data in storage, otherwise wait for producer to push data. 
            */
            unique_lock<mutex> storageUniqueLock(storageMutex);
            // how to pass "storage" in lambda 
            storageConditionVariable.wait( storageUniqueLock , [&]() { return storage.size() > 0 ? true : false ; });
            int returnVal = storage.back();
            storage.pop_back();
            storageConditionVariable.notify_one();
            return returnVal;
        }
};

void publishMethod(ProducerConsumerSimulation &simulationObject) { // publisher is one thread that is publishing data object
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        int randomNumber = rand() % 20;
        simulationObject.publish(randomNumber);
    }
}

void consumeMethod(ProducerConsumerSimulation &simulationObject) { // consumer is one thread which is consuming data from object
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        int result = simulationObject.consume();
        cout << " consumer thread got result " << result << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ProducerConsumerSimulation simulationObject;

    thread publisherThread(publishMethod, std::ref(simulationObject));
    thread consumerThread(consumeMethod, std::ref(simulationObject));

    publisherThread.join();

}
```

### So why wasn't it working?

C++ lambdas require that you specify the `captures`, if you don't then the lambda won't be able to access variables outside its scope but only its provided arguments.

There are many ways to use captures with Lambdas, I suggest [checking the C++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) on Lambdas.

But in this case, you needed to add the `&` symbol inside the `[]` (the `captures` of the lambda) to gain access to the `storage` variable by reference.

Or you could also use the `=` symbol since you don't need to modify the `storage` variable but I still suggest using references since doing a copy of the `storage` variable every time could negatively influence the program speed.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Nitpick: This answer works because `&` implicitly captures `this`, and then you can access `this->storage`. Though, as fabian explained in his comment, the `this->` part can be left out as long as there is no name conflict on `storage`. So in this case there is no difference between using `[&]` or `[this]`.